# file menu disappeared on android-studio on mac

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

Overnight the File, Edit, Build etc that used to be there on the top bar of my MacBook pro while running Android Studio 2.3.3 have disappeared. Could not find a method to bring them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found finally was to update the studio and the toolkit to latest android-studio

Answer (score 1):

You should hover the mouse in top and the menu will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Updating didn't work for me, since I was already on the latest version. Here's what worked for me:

For Android Studio 4.0.1, you can go to View > Appearance and toggle Toolbar:

[image: Toggle main toolbar]

The checkmark to the left of Toolbar means that Android Studio's Main Toolbar is toggled on and currently displays. No checkmark indicates the Main Toolbar is toggled off and disabled.